# Linear Regression of given data set

Tags: matlab

If I have a set of data how would I fit a line using linear regression? I know that I should use polyfit, however, I have to linearly interpolate the line after I find it so I don't know what would be the best set up.

My sample data set it

```
x = [ 0.13653 0.14551 0.28696 0.47473 0.48740 0.75441 0.88754 0.91808 0.94291 0.97388 ];
y = [ 0.29250 0.79586 0.78081 0.12643 0.14409 0.50125 0.40181 0.83697 0.34130 0.27120 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `polyfit` with `1` as the degree, so:

```
[a,b] = polyfit(x, y, 1)
```

`polyfit` will return a list containing 2 items: (1) the *slope* of the line `a`; and (2) the *intercept* `b`.

You can then plot the line with function `a*x+b` (`x` is here *not* the list).